# How to find relationships in combinations in one variable

Tags: r, transformation

I want to count how often different authors work together on titles. The given dataset looks like this:

```
Title  | Author
------ | ------
A      | ABC  
A      | DEF  
B      | ABC  
B      | GHI  
B      | JKL  
C      | ABC  
C      | JKL  
D      | GHI  
D      | DEF
E      | ABC
E      | JKL
F      | ABC
F      | JKL
```

My target table should look like this, where count means the number of titles the author worked together.

```
Author | Works with | Count
------ | ---------- | -----
ABC    | DEF        |     1    
ABC    | GHI        |     0
ABC    | JKL        |     3
DEF    | ABC        |     1
DEF    | GHI        |     2
...    | ...        |   ...
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide reproducible data or , at a minimum, don't include the pipes ("|"). The format that you provided is quite difficult to work with.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will keep it in mind. (The table format was suggested by this site. )

Comment: Conceptually, I tried **Tidyr** and **dplyer** but did not reach my target table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using base functions:

```
Title <- c("A","A","B","B","B","C","C","D","D","E","E","F","F")
Author <- c("ABC","DEF","ABC","GHI","JKL","ABC","JKL","GHI","DEF","ABC","JKL","ABC","JKL")

df <- data.frame(cbind(Title, Author))
df2 <- expand.grid(unique(df$Author), unique(df$Author)) #set up data frame with unique combinations of all authors

lauth <- tapply(df$Title, df$Author, FUN=function(x) paste(x)) #get vector of all titles that each author worked on
myfun <- function(x,y) sum(lauth[[x]] %in% lauth[[y]]) #function

df2$count <- mapply(myfun, x=df2$Var1, y=df2$Var2) #apply function to columns of dataframe
```

Comment: worked for me. Since df2 got very large I filtered all combinations with count > 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqldf package

```
target = sqldf("select a.author as a1,b.author as a2,count(*) as count from df a inner join df b on a.title = b.title group by a.author,b.author")
target <- target[!target$a1== target$a2,]
```

Comment: Was it of help ??

Comment: USe this as the on clause so that it does not give each pair twice.  Also this eliminates the need for the second line of code above.  `on a.title = b.title and a.author < b.author`

Answer (score 0):

Another base R solution using `table` and `crossprod` from user36.

```
# get counts of author interactions
counts <- crossprod(table(dat))

# construct data.frame from count results
mydf <- data.frame(author=rep(rownames(counts), each=nrow(counts)),
                   worksWith=rownames(counts),
                   count=c(counts))

# drop same author observations (equal to total number of pubs by author)
mydf <- mydf[mydf$author != mydf$worksWith,]
```

The first 6 rows of the resulting data.frame is

```
head(mydf)
  author worksWith count
2    ABC       DEF     1
3    ABC       GHI     1
4    ABC       JKL     4
5    DEF       ABC     1
7    DEF       GHI     1
8    DEF       JKL     0
```

**data**

```
dat <-
structure(list(Title = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
"F"), class = "factor"), Author = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("ABC", "DEF", 
"GHI", "JKL"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Title", "Author"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```